# Error message on entering duplicate in django form

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, email-validation

I am trying to avoid duplicate email in my website form . Till now I was able to do this:

1.Whenever I enter duplicate email, it navigate back to homepage and user is not saved{ In my case team is not joined}.

2.In admin page when I try to enter duplicate email , I get my error message of duplicate email address

I want this message in my form too, but it navigates to homepage.

***This is my model in models.py:***

```
class Team(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100,unique=True,error_messages={'unique':"Email already exists"})
    contact=models.IntegerField(null=False,blank=False,default=1234567890)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

***This is my form in forms.py:***

```
class TeamMembers(forms.ModelForm):
    username = forms.CharField(required=True,max_length=100)
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True,max_length=100,error_messages={'unique':"Email already exists"})
    contact=forms.IntegerField(required=True)    
    
    class Meta:
        model=Team
        fields = ['username','email','contact']
```

***This is my function in views.py***

```
def join_team(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = TeamMembers(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            form = TeamMembers()
            messages.success(request,"Joined team")
    else:
        form = TeamMembers()
    return render(request, 'user/join_team.html', {'form' : form })
```

***This is my join_team.html***

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{%load crispy_forms_tags%}
{% block content %}
    <div class="content-section">
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}

   
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Join our team</legend>
                {{form|crispy}}
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Join</button>
            </div>
        </form>

    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

I want to display error message on form page instead of going to homepage.

I am not able to find this question anywhere , so please help me!!

Comment: I was getting error message "The Team could not be created because the data didn't validate." but then I changed  **form.is_valid** to  form.is_valid()   and now I am navigating to homepage and nothing is saved in database (when I enter duplicate email)

Comment: You have shown your form again instead of view...

Comment: You copied `forms.py` two times. instead of copying `views.py`

Comment: Sorry for that mistake,I have corrected it now.